# What time does the Graph's Insights API refresh the attributes with day as the aggregation period?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

For example,
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/insights

For the aggregation period 'day', Does anyone know at what time does Facebook refresh that value?

I remember reading it to be around 8am, but I can't remember if it was accurate or where I read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check out the `endtime` you get inside the values ([Graph API Explorer request for `me?fields=insights.metric(page_stories)`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dinsights.metric(page_stories)&version=v2.12); supply your own page access token), for all three periods (day/wekk/days_28) it is of the form

```
2018-02-19T08:00:00+0000
```

Same time portion in each case.